# my name is a chinese name, anyi. how would i write the 'yi' part of my name in katakana?

Tags: katakana, names

i know there is no "yi" katakana. i know the approximation of ying is イン but in this case it does not work. do any native speakers know how to write yi in katana?

Comment: What’s the Chinese spelling?

Comment: it is pronounced as ānyì

Comment: You could also write your name in Chinese and simply use the Japanese pronunciation of the characters.  If you are familiar with [Yip Man (or Ip Man)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_Man), his name in written as 葉問.  This is pronounced in Japanese as Yо̄ Mon, and if you're familiar with the movie, that is exactly what the Japanese officials call him when they capture him.

Comment: thank you istrasci for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

アンイ An'i or アンイー An'ii would be the normal representation on similar Chinese names, such as [Gu Lingyi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A4%E9%9C%8A%E7%9B%8A) or [Ju Jingyi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9E%A0%E5%A9%A7%E7%A6%95).

Comment: thank you so much!